# VBA code for adding todays date in the sbject while sending email

Tags: vba, excel

I have copied the VBA Code for sending status update mail form the selected cells in excel.
But now I wanted to change the code to add todays date in to the code so while sending status mail it will pick todays date in the subject and in introduction section. Below is the code

```
Sub Send_Range()
      ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B5").Select
      ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
      With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
      .Introduction = "This is a sample worksheet."
      .Item.To = "E-Mail_Address_Here"
      .Item.Subject = "My subject"
      .Item.Send
   End With
End Sub
```

Please help

Answer (score 4):

Add the `Date` function:

```
.Item.Subject = "My subject " & Date
```

Comment: You can also use `Format()` to get the date in the desired format if the default is not suitable. E.g. `.Item.Subject = "My Subject " & Format(Date, "dd/MM/yyyy")`